# NSURLConnection Returns Null in some parameters

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, nsurlconnection

This is [my URL](http://ws.spotify.com/search/1/track.json?q=Para%20Qu%C3%A9%20Volviste). I need to get data from this URL..it will return the value for english words..but if i give parameter like "Para Qué Volviste"..then it returns null..Please help me ..

My code is

```
 NSURLConnection * connectionGetISRC=[[NSURLConnection alloc]initWithRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://ws.spotify.com/search/1/track.json?q=Para Qué Volviste"]] delegate:self];
    [connectionGetISRC start];


-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
{
    dataJson=[NSMutableData data];
}

-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
{
    NSLog(@"dat %@",data);
    [dataJson appendData:data];
}

-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    NSLog(@"error %@",error.description);
    [hud hide:YES];
}

-(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{
    id dict=[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:dataJson options:kNilOptions error:nil];
    NSLog(@"dataJson %@",dataJson);
    NSLog(@"dicvt %@",dict);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to percent-escape your URL's parameter, but take care to not be seduced by `stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding`. That takes care of spaces fine (which is the immediate problem), but if you had some other reserved characters in it, it would fail (e.g. notably if your parameter had `&` or `+` characters in it). If you want to handle these sorts of characters, you really should use `CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes` instead:

```
NSString* urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://ws.spotify.com/search/1/track.json?q=%@", [self percentEscapeString:@"Para Qué Volviste"]];
NSURLConnection * connectionGetISRC=[[NSURLConnection alloc]initWithRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString] delegate:self];
// [connectionGetISRC start];
```

Where, `percentEscapeString` calls `CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes`:

```
- (NSString *)percentEscapeString:(NSString *)string
{ 
    return CFBridgingRelease(CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes(kCFAllocatorDefault,
                                                                     (CFStringRef)string,
                                                                     NULL,
                                                                     (CFStringRef)@":/?@!$&'()*+,;=",
                                                                     kCFStringEncodingUTF8));
}
```

As an aside, the `initWithRequest:delegate:` automatically starts the connection, so you should not be manually calling the `start` method. As [the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLConnection_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001697-SW4) for `start` says:

> Calling this method is necessary only if you create a connection with the `initWithRequest:delegate:startImmediately:` method and provide `NO` for the `startImmediately` parameter.

Answer (score 3):

you should encode you request parameters before intiating connection like below,

```
NSString* urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://ws.spotify.com/search/1/track.json?q=%@",[@"Para Qué Volviste" stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

NSURL* url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];

NSURLConnection * connectionGetISRC=[[NSURLConnection alloc]initWithRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url] delegate:self];
[connectionGetISRC start];
```

Answer (score 3):

look like the space in your URL a problem. try this connection srting

```
 NSString *str=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://ws.spotify.com/search/1/track.json?q=Para Qué Volviste"];
str=[str stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSURLConnection * connectionGetISRC=[[NSURLConnection alloc]initWithRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:str]] delegate:self];
[connectionGetISRC start];
```